# How to override css for giving background image?

Tags: html, css

I have one page and I have applied style.css to it and in that body has given by default one background Image which will set automatically by adding css file to that page.
But in that I want all formatting same but I want to change body background image.

So what I will have to do to override the css formatting ?

In `style.css` I have given :

```
body
{
     background: url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-x #e4e9ec top;
}
```

But I want bg.png as it's background So I have used :

```
<body background="images/noise-bg.png">
```

Is there any way ?

Comment: why don't you just change the css then?

Comment: Add `!important` flag?

Comment: @Prisoner - Because in all other my page I have to use that background image.

Comment: @Thew - Sorry sir what you say I don't understand.

Comment: @user2659972ღ As you can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cmfCB/) fiddle, adding `!important` after your css code will over ride whatever has been given. `!important` will override everything, and even if that has been given multiple times, it will take the last given `!important`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<body style="background-image: url(images/noise-bg.png)">
```

In terms of specificity, the style attribute should be more specific than styles defined in a stylesheet.

[image]

You can read more about CSS specificity here: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Sir it works but when I am giving `repeat-x #e4e9ec top` to it, it not works. Image is of small size so I have to `use repeat-x`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background-image` property.

Comment: Set it to a different value.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a different id attribute to the body tag for pages in your site.

For example for the home page you can use:

```
<body id="home">
```

And for another page you can use:

```
<body id="other">
```

Obviously these id names are just examples, use the ones that make most sense for your site.

Then in the CSS you can target specific pages like:

```
body#home {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-x #e4e9ec top;
}
```

And for another page you could use:

```
body#other {
  background: url(images/another-bg.jpg) repeat-x #e4e9ec top;
}
```

Hope that helps.